# Multirows, with text to move through parameters when creating a Table

Tags: multirow

I am trying to do the table below for one of my assignments. I have tried to do so through different variations. However, my text just does not end up being centered properly within the borders of the table.

I would like to see on how to make the text flow down, because of borders, without having to create different multicolumns, and inputing the words separately.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

This is some very scuffed code but to give an idea with what I am trying to do. Just missing really the whole alignment

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \textbf{\caption{Design Specifications}}
    \begin{tabular}{|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|}
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{1cm}{\textbf{Power (kW)}} &
    \multirow{5}{1cm}{\textbf{Input Speed (rpm)}} &
    \multirow{5}{1.5cm}{\textbf{Speed Ratio (in/out)}} &
    \multirow{5}{1.5cm}{\textbf{Reliability (\%)}} &
    \multirow{5}{2.cm}{\textbf{Lifespan (Years of 24/7 Operation)}} &
    \multirow{5}{3cm}{\textbf{Housing Type: 1.Open Gearing 2.Commerical Enclosed}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Operating Conditions}} &
    \cline{7-8}
    & & & & & &
    \multirow{4}{3cm}{\textbf{Power: 1.Uniform 2.Light Shock 3. Medium Shock}} &
    \multirow{4}{3.5cm}{\textbf{Driven Machine: 1.Uniform 2.Moderate Shock 3.Heavy Shock}} &
    & & & & & & & &
    & & & & & & & &
    & & & & & & & &
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Have a look at `tabularray` package.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have, but it still does not solve my problem. My problem is just trying to align everything within a vertical axis on each single one

Comment: Your question is unclear. Beside this, provided code fragment is very erroneous. Why you use multirow` cells, if they not span any adjacent rows?

Answer (score 1):

- Quite late, but it may help someone ...
- As I already mentioned in my comment to question, your question is not clear:

  - You not provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document, which reproduce your problem.
  - Why you use `\multirow` cells when they are not any column with text in the five rows?
  - Code fragment is erroneous. Rows are not terminated by `\\`.
  - Column type `M` is undefined.
  - Your answer is not of any help, since it can not be tested and by this confirmed, that it really solve your problem.
- I guessing, that possible solution is simple to remove all `\multirow` commands from cells in the first row of your code fragment.
- BTW, your table is quite wide with some very long column headers. You should consider to rephrase them (if possible) that would become shorter.
- Let me spell out suggestion in the @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[font={small, bf}]{caption}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Design Specifications}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
            colspec = {*{8}{X[c]}},
            colsep  = 3pt,
            row{1}  = {c, font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
            }
Power (kW)
   &   Input Speed (rpm)
       &   Speed Ratio (in/out)
           &   Reliability (\%)
               &   Lifespan (Years of 24/7 Operation)
                   &   Housing Type: 1.Open Gearing 2.Commerical Enclosed
                       &   \SetCell[c=2]{} Operating Conditions
                           &   \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
A case when column headers are shortened and they meaning explained in the table notes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[font={small, bf}]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Design Specifications}
\begin{talltblr}[
    entry=none,     % <---
    label=none,     % <---
note{a} = {Open Gear},
note{b} = {Commerical Enclosed},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {*{8}{X[l]}},
                    colsep  = 3pt,
                    row{1}  = {c, font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
                    }
Power (kW)
    &   Input Speed (rpm)
        &   Speed Ratio (in/out)
            &   Reliability (\%)
                &   Lifespan (Years of Operation)
                    &   Housing Types: OG\TblrNote{a} or CE\TblrNote{b}
                        &   \SetCell[c=2]{} Operating Conditions
                            &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

\centering within the multirow solved it

```
\multirow{5}{1cm}{\centering{\textbf{Power (kW)}}}
```

Comment: Your answer is not possible to verify and cannot help anyone. Extend it to complete small document, which consider code fragment from your question and which we can test.